# dense set in $c_o(\Bbb{Z})$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, dense-subspaces

Let's consider the sequence space $c_o(\Bbb{Z}) = \{(a_n)_{n \in \Bbb{Z}} : lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a_n) = 0\}$ equipped with the usual norm $\lVert.\rVert_{l^{\infty}}$.
For any $k \in \Bbb{Z}$, let $e^{(k)} \in c_o(\Bbb{Z})$ be the sequence defined as $e^{(k)}_n := \delta_{nk}$ ($\forall n \in \Bbb{Z}$).

I read somewhere that $\{e^{(k)}\}_{k \in \Bbb{Z}}$ is a dense set in $c_o(\Bbb{Z})$ but it seems untrue. I might be missing something very obvious here but for example, I don't see why the sequence $a := (...,0 ,0 ,1, 1, 0, 0, 0,...) \in c_o(\Bbb{Z})$ would be arbitrarily close from one of the $e^{(k)}$. For me, the distance that this sequence has from $\{e^{(k)}\}_{k \in \Bbb{Z}}$ is just given by 1.

Could you please enlighten me ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Isn't $c_0(\mathbb Z) = \{ (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb Z} \colon \lim_{|n| \to \infty} a_n=0\}$? In that case, what is true is that the $\operatorname{span}_{k\in \mathbb Z}\{e^{(k)}\}$ is dense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of $c_0(\mathbb Z)$ is not quite right: it is the set of all bilateral sequences $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb Z}$ that "vanish at infinity", meaning that $\lim_{|k| \to \infty} a_k=0.$

What you are trying to show is not true. What is true however is that  $\operatorname{span}_{k\in \mathbb Z}\{e^{(k)}\}$ is dense in $c_0$. To see this, take $x=(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb Z} \in c_0(\mathbb Z)$ and let $ε>0$. Pick $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that for $|n| \ge n_0, \ |x_n|<\varepsilon.$ If we let
$$y= x_{-n_0+1} e^{(n_0-1) } + \dots + x_0 e^{(0)}+x_1 e^{(1)} + \dots + x_{n_0-1} e^{(n)}$$
then
$$\| y-x\|_{\infty} = \sup_{|n| \ge n_0} |x_n| \le \varepsilon. $$

Comment: What do you mean with bilateral sequences?

Comment: It means sequences defined on the integers (not just the natural numbers)

Comment: I am sorry, I can't make sense of "sequences from the integers to the reals", could you elaborate on that? Thank you. Regarding the edit: So it means the entries of the sequence take integers instead of natural numbers? As an example: $(0,1,2,-3,4,-5,...)$ would be a bilateral sequence because it is defined on integers and $(0,1,2,3,\dots)$ is a "unilateral" sequence?

Comment: A (normal) sequence is an element of $\mathbb F ^ {\mathbb N}$ where $\mathbb F$ is your field of choise. They are denoted by $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$. A bilateral sequence on the other hand is an element of $\mathbb F ^ {\mathbb Z}$ and are denoted by $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb Z}$. The difference is that the indices now run over all integers, not just the positive ones. So $(1,-2,3,-4,\dots)$ is a (normal sequence) whereas $ (\dots, -2, \frac 12, 4,5,\dots) $ is a bilateral sequence

Comment: Oh I see, interesting, haven't heard about them. Thank you!